# Can Visual Studio block select like VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

When I use block select via `VS Code`, I can select the following all.

```
Name
Country
Birthday
```

But with `Visual Studio`, I can only select rectangle area like:

```
Name
Coun
Birt
```

or (added to reply comment)

```
Name{get
Country{
Birthday
```

How to make `Visual Studio` work like `VS Code`?

Add:
I mean, with VS Code I can use shift+ctrl+right to select jagged whole words in multi-line, but Visual Studio only select a rectangle area.

Comment: Did you try starting bottom-right?

Comment: you mean windows-logo key? that only move the application window

Comment: No, *selecting* from bottom-right, whether using a *pointing device* or the keyboard.

Comment: I edited my question, so if I selecting from bottom-right, it will still be rectangle and I will select some character that I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you looking for an "Expand selection" in VS Code alternative for Visual Studio.

[image]

As in Microsoft documentation, you can use "Shift + Alt + =" this will select the block where the cursor point and if you press multiple time then it expand to a higher level as well.

[more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&utm_source=vshelp#bkmk_text-editor-context-specific-shortcuts)